# New operator overloading causes Infinite recursion when inserting the address in a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, memory-leaks, operator-overloading

I am overloading the new operator to write my own custom memory monitoring class which has a map of address to bytes.

but unfortunately when I insert the address of the memory to a map, the map will create a new object and the overloaded new operator will get called again and creates a infinite recursion and memory leak.

I have added the code that causes the issue below.
Please advice.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>


using namespace std;
class MemoryManager{ 
  static map<void* const, size_t> memory;  //void* is an address, size_t is size
  static void allocate(void* ptr, size_t size);
}

void MemoryManager::allocate(void* ptr, size_t size){
   cout << ptr << endl; // prints the address

   // inserts the address of the memory in a map.
   // the compiler will create `new` object and creates a recursion.
   // infinite recursion is created.
   memory.insert(pair<void* const, size_t>(ptr, size));

   totalBytes += size;

   number_of_allocations++;

}


void* operator new (size_t size){

  void* ptr = malloc(size);

  MemoryManager::allocate(ptr, size);

  return ptr;
}




int main(){


   int* p1 = new int;

}
```

Comment: A memory leak, really? It almost looks like infinite recursion to me (assuming that your `std::allocator` uses the global `operator new`). Hm, coming to think of it, I'm not sure if standard library container APIs are guaranteed to be reentrant.

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't ever use `new` or overload/replace allocation functions. If you want to customize allocation, a pure-library approach like allocators seems to be more versatile and tractable.

Comment: Yeah I updated the thread, it's generating infinite recursion.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. The short answer is, don't do that. The slightly longer, but no more useful, answer is that your special map may need a special allocator that doesn't itself use the replaced allocation function.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that.

If you must, get a copy of "the mallocator", the world's simplest allocator that uses malloc, or write one yourself.  Use that allocator in your `std::map` to avoid it calling (non-placement) `new`.